# No module named 'signals' in Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm practice Django and I'm trying to make function
( **Ready** ) in the app.py and import
( **users.signals** ) into this function and I already used
**pip install signals** to install signals package and didn't solve it yet.

apps.py

```
    from django.apps import AppConfig
    class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
        name = 'users'
    
        def ready(self):
            import users.signals
```

signals.py

```
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.dispatch import receiver
    from .models import Profile
    
    
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    
    
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

**No module named 'signals'**

Comment: Why "I already used pip install signals"? You need to import code from a file, not from outside package :) Do you have signals in the same folder as given apps.py?

Comment: @NixonSparrow Yes apps.py & signals.py in the same folder

Comment: We need more info about what error you're facing and all the relevant code that could be causing the issue.